# dynamic form rendering with twig

Tags: symfony, matrix, twig, silex

I'm using silex to build an election simulator app and I need to render a form using the twig template engine. Problem is, the size of the form will depend on the previous form's results and I need to render each field in its corresponding row. It looks very much like a matrix.

In the following example, Lists A and B got more than 10% in the first round so they advance to the second. You can then define the "report" of the votes from all lists that entered the election.

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/970049form.jpg

Each row is generated like so:

```
foreach($first_round_lists as $list)
{
    foreach($winners as $key => $winner)
    {
        $form->add('list'.$i.$key, null, array('label' => false, 'attr'=> array('class'=>'entry data', 'maxlength'=>'5', 'value'=>'')));
    }
    $form->add('blanks-list'.$i, null, array('label' => false, 'attr'=> array('class'=>'entry data', 'maxlength'=>'5', 'value'=>'')));
    $form->add('abstention-list'.$i, null, array('label' => false, 'attr'=> array('class'=>'entry data', 'maxlength'=>'5', 'readonly'=>"readonly")));
    $i++;
}
```

Any ideas on how I could render this properly using twig ?

Comment: Make a custom form field for your needs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: solved it the ugly way, storing my inputs indexes in an two dimensions array and iterating on it, rendering each form input like so:
{{ form_widget(form.children[input]) }}